# How much mass does a person lose in a day through breathing and perspiration?

Tags: biochemistry, breathing

Water and carbon are lost through perspiration and breathing.

How much mass is lost in this way in a single day for a typical person?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's considered a requisite on biology.se that at least some research is carried out and presented with your question. Otherwise it will be closed as *homework*. The [site tour](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help)  provide guidance on how to use this site. Please take a few minutes to read about the kind of questions which are on topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest route to your answer would be through the kcal consumed/expended equation.

1kg (2.2lbs) of fat has ~7700 kcal of energy. The average person requires roughly 2000kcal per day if they perform mild physical labor throughout their day - 25.9% of the total energy available in 1kg of fat. So you could say that if a person did not eat for a day they would lose ~1/4kg or 1/2lb of fat-mass.

I calculated the above in "fat" because it's the number I knew off-hand, but truth be told the amount of "mass" you'd lose also depends on density. Fat (9kcal/g) is more energy dense than alcohol (7kcal/g), carbohydrates/sugars (4kcal/g), and protein (4kcal/g). For the same energy expenditure of 2000kcal in a single day you would metabolise more than 1/2kg or 1lb of either carbohydrates or proteins.

In reality you will burn roughly equal amounts of fats and carbohydrates (assuming you're not forcing your body into a ketogenic state) at about a 55% fat/45% carbs ratio IIRC.

So, with the assumption that the person isn't on a keto diet, has sufficient fat reserves, and expends 2000kcal of energy in a single day while drinking enough water to replace what is used in the energy metabolism, you will lose ~.14kg of fat and ~.63kg of carbohydrates for a grand total of ***~.77kg (~1.69lbs)*** of mass expended per day.

Since humans vary greatly, however, that is going to vary wildly. Personally speaking, it's easy for me to expend >3000kcal per day with an hour of moderate exercise since I'm simply *bigger* than the average person and require more energy to do anything. If you're shorter than average, do less work than average (i.e. - are sedentary), or hormonal conditions (which are **rare** and *cannot* be self-diagnosed) modify calorie expenditure, your numbers will be different.

Also worth it to note: Ghrelin, a major hunger-regulating hormone, changes its tonic behavior significantly if you go more than 2 days consuming less than 1200kcal. After 2 days fasting it will instigate changes that will result in more fat *retained* after you resume a regular eating schedule *for up to 5 years*... So starving yourself for a week to lose 5kg seems great until you realize you'll gain 10kg once you go back to a normal diet.

As always, if you're unsure of any diets please go to a qualified professional for consultation.

Comment: I would like to point out that the unit used here in the answer, kcal = 1000 cal = 1 Cal. Note that the unit Cal is also called food calorie and equals 1000 of the calories unit used in chemistry